# SQL Server - To get all connected server names

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

In SQL Server 2000/2005, I want to get the names of all connected servers. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

exec sp_helpserver

Answer (score 1):

In addition to sp_helpserver, you can get additional information from sys.servers.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.servers
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search your entire network in order to retrieve comprehensive information for all SQL Server Instances in your topology you can use the freely available Quest Discovery Wizard.

[Quest Discovery Wizard for SQL Server](http://www.quest.com/discovery-wizard-for-sql-server/)